# Writing to Cosmos DB very slow (using .Net SDK)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am writing a console app (eventually to be an Azure Function) to retrieve some data, and write it to a container in Cosmos DB (currently using SQL version, but could use table storage as instead).

Making 10 million calls to Upsert, as in the below code, takes about 20 hours! Any recommendations to improve the speed significantly?

```cs
static async Task AddToDatabase(List<Product> products)
{
    var client = new CosmosClient(connectionString, new CosmosClientOptions { AllowBulkExecution = true, EnableContentResponseOnWrite = false, SerializerOptions = new CosmosSerializationOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase } });
    var container = client.GetContainer(databaseName, containerName);
    var tasks = products.Select(p => container.UpsertItemAsync(p, new PartitionKey(p.Barcode)).ContinueWith(t => UpdateProgress()));
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: You can refer to [Diagnose and troubleshoot Azure Cosmos DB .NET SDK slow requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-dot-net-sdk-slow-request?tabs=cpu-new) and [Performance tips for Azure Cosmos DB and .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/performance-tips-dotnet-sdk-v3-sql)

Comment: How are you calling `AddToDatabase` method? How many products are being passed to this method?

Comment: How many RU's on the container you are writing to? and do you see any 429 responses at all? using Bulk insert its pretty easy to rack up a lot of RU's and thus the retries will kill your performance as the default is 9 times

Comment: Most important is to determine if any more is actually possible. You'll need to use 10000000 * X RU for your upserts (where X is the average cost) and you complete this in 20*3600 seconds. If the RU/s of that (almost) matches your database config there's nothing you can do apart from scaling it up first (or maybe turn indexing off to lower the RU charge at the cost of having no indexing for a while).

Comment: Another question is: Are you calling AddToDatabase multiple times? Each call is creating a CosmosClient, the CosmosClient instance should be a Singleton and shared, not created each time.